# AND operator on Laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to fetch 3 values = 2 select forms and 1 from date form and compare it to the one's on my database if it's equal but whenever I tried to compare the 3 of them using the AND operator in laravel, it doesn't give me any details. How can I compare them correctly?

**OnewayflightController.php**

```
public function onewayflightresults()
    {
      $search1 = Input::get('destinationto');
      $search2 = Input::get('destinationfrom');
      $search3 = Input::get('departure');
      $results = DB::table('oneways')->where('destinationto','=',$search1)
                                     ->where('destinationfrom','=',$search2)
                                     ->where('destinationfrom','=',$search3)
                                     ->get();
      var_dump($results);
    }
```

**Database:**

id-1

destinationto-Australia

destinationfrom-Japan

departure-01-2-14

**onewayflight.blade.php**

```
      <div>
                {{ Form::label('label','From: ') }}
                {{ Form::select('destinationfrom', $destinationfrom)}}
      </div>
      <div>     

                {{ Form::label('destinationto','To: ') }} 
                {{ Form::select('destinationto', $destinationto)}}
      </div>
      <div>
           {{ Form::label('departure','Departure:', array('class'=>'"input-group-addon btn"'))}}
           {{ Form::text('departure', '', array('id' => 'calendar')) }} <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> 
{{ Form::close() }}
```

**UPDATE**

I've changed

`->where('destinationfrom','=',$search3)`

to

`->where('departure','=',$search3)`

But still gives me no results.

Comment: Please make sure your $search variables get values which you need. if that values are invalid then you will not get correct output. and just compare your database values with your search values

Comment: Based for the result of var_dump, it shows the result it need. But when I try to compare the three of them, it doesn't show results.

Comment: You mean to say your query get result what you need ?

Comment: When I try to var_dump them individually but if I'd try var_dump on $results, It wouldn't show any results

Comment: Please can you provide some more information like how your data look like (your database record) and your search values so that we can figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Your third `where` should be searching `departure`, not `destinationfrom` a second time.

Comment: Updated it but still no results

Answer (score 0):

Problem with

```
->where('destinationfrom','=',$search3)
```

Update your to

```
->where('departure','=',$search3)
```

I think that will work.

Comment: Never saw that typo. Updated it but still, nothing returns.

Answer (score 0):

Need to update you third where condition. you are comparing destinationfrom value two times.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking to a collection, and think that is not a result.

Try:

```
foreach($results as $result)
{
  var_dump($result);
}
```

This will dump all the rows found with your input. Only want 1 result? change `->get();` to `->firstOrFail()`. Then you can dump `$results` without a foreach.

Or maybe a subquery is the solution?

```
$results = DB::table('oneways')
               ->where('destinationto', '=', $search1)
               ->where('destinationfrom', '=', $search2)
               ->where(function($query) {
                        return $query->where('departure', '=', $search3)
                })
        ->get();
```

Is there only 1 result you are trying to get? Maybe this is better:

```
$results = DB::table('oneways')
               ->where('destinationto', '=', $search1)
               ->where('destinationfrom', '=', $search2)
               ->where(function($query) {
                        return $query->where('departure', '=', $search3)
                })
        ->firstOrFail();
```

This will give you 1 result, not a collection.

If this doens't work, you can try dumping your input to check if its filled correctly:

```
public function onewayflightresults()
{
   dd(Input::all());
   // Rest of the code
}
```

If the values in `Input::all();` are exactly the same as the values in your database, the query should give you the result. If not, try this to futher debug:

```
dd(DB::table('oneways')->where('id', '=', 1)->first());
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply sir. I have tried executing the codes that you've suggested but it gives me Undefined variable: search3. 

P.S I've changed the second $search1 into $search3

Comment: You got undefined variable after changing search 1 into search 3?